# Changes to ng-options object not updating to html

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ng-options

When I select an item, the input elements update. However, after I save any changes, the element becomes unbound to the ng-model object. Sorry if this is a simple question, I searched for several hours and couldn't figure it out. Thankyou!

HTML

```
<div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MyController">
  <label>Message Name</label><br>
  <input id="msgName" type="text" value="{{selectedMsg.name}}"><br>

  <label>Load Message</label><br>
  <select id="msgSelect" ng-model="selectedMsg" ng-options="msg.name for msg in Messages"></select><br>

  <label><br>
    Message Text
  </label><br>
  <textarea id="msgText">{{selectedMsg.text}}</textarea><br>
  <button id="saveBtn">SaveMessage</button>

</div>
```

Javascript

```
let msg1 = {
  name: "Message 1",
  text: "This is Message 1's text."
}
let msg2 = {
  name: "Message 2",
  text: "This is Message 2's text."
}

let messages = [msg1, msg2];

let app = angular.module('MyApp', []);
app.controller('MyController', function ($scope){
  scope = $scope;
  scope.Messages = messages;
}); 
$('#saveBtn').on('click', () => {
  scope.selectedMsg.name = $('#msgName').val();
  scope.selectedMsg.text = $('#msgText').val();
  scope.$apply();
});
```

[Link to codepen.](https://codepen.io/motion333/pen/OBQyvP)

Comment: Your code is mix up of jquery, javascript and angularjs. Just any one of them.

Comment: Was that in reference to the tags I included in the question? If so, I edited to the only tag is angularjs.

Comment: No. It's a reaction to your code: you're using jQuery. Don't. use AngularJS (ng-click, ng-model, etc.).

Comment: So I updated my code to only use angularjs, and I got it working, although I feel like I'm doing something wrong. (I don't think i should need a selectionChanged function.) [link](https://jsbin.com/jupucus/edit?html,js,output) (codepen is down) Should I delete this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you don't need the interpolation brackets on the `input` or `textarea`.  That's what 2-way binding is for and it's ultimately what `ng-model` does behind the scenes.

Your comment is correct that you don't need an `ng-change` in the select either, that's the beauty of reactivity.  Here is what your template should look like:

```
<select ng-model="selectedMsg" ng-options="msg.name for msg in Messages"></select><br>

<label>Message Name</label><br>
<input type="text" ng-model="selectedMsg.name"><br>

<label><br>
  Message Text
</label><br>
<textarea ng-model="selectedMsg.text"></textarea><br>
```

You can see that the inputs all share an object model, specifically the textbox and textarea binding to properties of the object selected by the `select`.

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/sh0ber/0kdf5u8w/)